# Eclipse Project Name in Git Repositories Window

Tags: eclipse, ide

When I import java project from git repository section in eclipse, The **>** sign is added to the project name like this =>  **> network [master]**.
I want to know that what is this sign? Is my project fully imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unstaged changes** are marked with the **`>`** sign by default (similar to CVS, SVN, etc.):

***Window > Preferences: Team > Git > Label Decoration***

One or more files have been added, deleted or modified (also called *dirty*). In your case, a file was probably created by Eclipse after successful importing when creating the project. You can see all these unstaged changes in the ***Git Staging*** view.